# Intent to google map not working

Tags: android, google-maps, location, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadCastReciver in my app which listen for incoming sms. 
I want to when sms receive, application open the google map via intent. This is my code but I don't know where is my mistake. 
Thank's for any help.

BroadcastReciver.class:

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    startAct(message, context);
                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }
    private void startAct(String message, Context con) {

        double Mylatitude = 12;
        double Mylongitude = 11;
        GPSTracker tracker = new GPSTracker(con);
        if (tracker.canGetLocation()) {
            Mylatitude = tracker.getLatitude();
            Mylongitude = tracker.getLongitude();
        }

        String location = message;
        String ACC_lat = location.substring(0, location.indexOf(","));
        String ACC_lang = location.substring(location.indexOf(",") + 1, location.length());
        Toast.makeText(con, ACC_lang + " ^ " + ACC_lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Mylatitude + "," + Mylongitude + "&daddr=" + ACC_lat + "," + ACC_lang));
    con.startActivity(mapIntent);

   }
```

I also added it in `manifest.xml` file

Comment: So you checked that you have corrected latitude, longitude, ACC_lat and ACC_lang?

Comment: Print your logs if possible. And where are you getting problem? Are you using androidM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split URI into two parts, use one in costructor of Intent and other as package. Here is [more details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents), how to send intents.

Sample:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```